# Getting HTTP ERROR 500 : laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm working with laravel5.5 using xampp server(7.2) in ubuntu os.I have created a project lara using command (composer create-project laravel/laravel lara) and getting this inside opt/lampp/htdocs/lara.but while i'm running this in browser through url servername/lara/public,getting like this:

> This page isn’t working
>
> servername is currently unable to handle this request.
>       HTTP ERROR 500

Can anyone suggest me where i'm going wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run this command inside project folder and try  `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: After that set public, storage and bootstrap/cache folder writable by the webserver.

Comment: after running command php artisan key:generate getting error   file_get_contents(/opt/lampp/htdocs/lara1/.env): failed to open stream: No   
  such file or directory

Comment: try to run from homestead, it is must better than xampp. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead